# tmux does not retain $PATH

Tags: ruby, path, zsh, tmux, zshrc

I am using [`chruby`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) to manage changing my rubies.

I also use `tmux`.

When I change to a different Ruby, chruby updates the `PATH` environment variable to include the path to the Ruby I want. When I start a tmux session, these modifications to PATH are lost.

How can I get `tmux` to retain the `PATH` variable when creating a new session?

**UPDATE**

I think I just need to read the instructions more carefully!

I have moved the `source` line from `~/.zshrc` to `~/.zprofile`

```
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
```

Now when I create a tmux session, the `PATH` includes the path to my Ruby, but it doesn't work because the `PATH` ends up duplicated like this:

**Before**

> /Users/jord/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin:/Users/jord/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin:/Users/jord/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/Users/jord/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

**After**

> /Users/jord/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/jord/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin:/Users/jord/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin:/Users/jord/.rubie
>   s/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/Users/jord/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/sbin

I assume this is because of the way I am setting my PATH in `~/.zshrc`?

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Should I just explicitly state my path? Or should that not be set in `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: You ever figure this out? Having similar issues with tmux

Comment: No, sorry. I don't use zsh or chruby anymore. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This should have been fixed in [0.3.0](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/issues/46), what version of chruby are you using?

Comment: I am using chruby version 0.3.4, but see above :)